# I've been trying to extend base Visual Composer element (vc_row)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to extend base Visual Composer element (vc_row):

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die('-1');
class My_Class {
    function __construct() {
        // ...
        add_action('init', array($this, 'vc_integrate'));
    }

    public function vc_integrate() {
        if(function_exists('vc_add_params')) {
            vc_add_params('vc_row', array(
                array(
                    'param_name'  => 'some_param',
                    // ...
                )
            ));
        }
    }
}
new My_Class();
```

I need to render this updated shortcode, but I don't want to replace standard template of the 'vc_row'.
I need to do the additional rendering after native rendering of the 'vc_row'.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: I found function `vc_theme_after_vc_row`, but it can be used only in one plugin.